# Performance issue with syscolpars system table in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

Hi we are having an important performance hit on a DB when we switched from 2008 R2 to 2016.  The database is use as a publication for other servers and when its publication is created we are having a 2 seconds delay when we do a "script table as create to ...".  The issue ain't really related to this operation, its just a symptoms (because it was very fast before we published it).  The main issue is that the same type of query is made when you do a snapshot, its check the table structure by querying the sysobjects and sys.all_columns columns which are VERY slow.

Here's the results of STATISTICS IO:

```
(13 row(s) affected)
Table 'syssingleobjrefs'. Scan count 53, logical reads 117, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysclsobjs'. Scan count 0, logical reads 26, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysnsobjs'. Scan count 1, logical reads 27, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysschobjs'. Scan count 2, logical reads 62, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysscalartypes'. Scan count 1, logical reads 53, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'syscolpars'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15646, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysobjvalues'. Scan count 15, logical reads 45, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'sysidxstats'. Scan count 13, logical reads 26, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'syscolpars'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'syspalvalues'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)
```

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1343 ms,  elapsed time = 1871 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1937 ms,  elapsed time = 2469 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

We can clearly see its doing a ton of reads here:

Table 'syscolpars'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15646

This table can also be seen as the main performance hitter in the execution plan:

[Execution Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMaAe.png)

You can see its using the clustered index of that syscolpars (system table) and i've noticed a change in this index between 2008 R2 and 2016.

In 2008 R2 the clustered columns are:

1. ColumnName
2. ID

While in 2016 it changed it's:

1. ID
2. ColumnName

So because its no longer clustered by its name first, its doing a CLustered index Scan operation, while in 2008 R2 its doing a Clustered Index Seek operation.

Because of this the snapshot is taking 4 hours to take vs 10 minutes on 2008 R2.

[sys.syscolpars indexes between 2008 R2 and 2016](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WloVO.png)

Anyone have an idea why they set the ID as the first column of their Clustered Index on that syscolpars system table?  And also how can i change that (You can't edit a system index).

Thanks for helping me understand this issue!

Comment: I'd report this to Microsoft. Maybe they did not realize that this has performance implications. They could at least add a non-clustered index back to fix this regression.

Comment: Yeah my plan was to add one myself until i've learned that it wasn't possible to do any on a system table, even in DAC mode...  Guess my only solution is to report this and wait for a fix.

I just don't understand why the clustered is now with the identity first, it doesn't make any sense for me.  Most use cases would be to find a column by its name and since its now in the 2nd columns in the index its no longer usable clustered index seek operations.

Comment: I believe I am seeing this as well in 2017. @PhilippeMorin, did you ever report to MS?